# How to use JWT Token Authorization and Azure AZ Token Authorization Simultaneously in DOTNET Core

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt, authorization, bearer-token

Trying to Implement the Authorization using both the JWT Token and Azure AD Token using the below code.
Individually this are working fine but I want to combine both like Azure AD and JWT Token Authorization in DOTNET Core 7 WEB API. When I try to combine both then I get the error as "scheme already exists bearer".

How do I implement both this logic in Program.cs file of DOTNET 7 API. This is the below code.

1. For Azure AD :

   ```
   builder.Services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
       .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")).EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
   ```
2. For JWT Token :

   ```
   builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                  .AddJwtBearer(jwtBearerOptions =>
                  { 
                      jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                      {
                          ValidateAudience = true,
                          ValidateLifetime = true,
                          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                          ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                          ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                          IssuerSigningKey = signingConfigurations.Key,
                          ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                      }; 
                  });
   ```

Implementing JWT Token authorization and Azure AD Authorization in DOTNET Core Program.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because you have not specified authentication scheme names for AzureAD and JWT authentication. By default, they both have the same name "Bearer".

The method [AddAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.authenticationservicecollectionextensions.addauthentication?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-authenticationservicecollectionextensions-addauthentication(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-string)) specifies a scheme name, that should be used by default when no name specified by the attribute [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "SomeScheme")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute.authenticationschemes?view=aspnetcore-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthenticationSchemes)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
    // add JWT Bearer
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, jwtBearerOptions =>
    {
        jwtBearerOptions.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
            IssuerSigningKey = signingConfigurations.Key,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    })
    // add AzureAD
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Official docs:
[AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebapiauthenticationbuilderextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapi?view=msal-model-dotnet-latest#microsoft-identity-web-microsoftidentitywebapiauthenticationbuilderextensions-addmicrosoftidentitywebapi(microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-authenticationbuilder-microsoft-extensions-configuration-iconfigurationsection-system-string-system-boolean))
and [AddJwtBearer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-jwtbearerextensions-addjwtbearer(microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-authenticationbuilder-system-string-system-action((microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-jwtbearer-jwtbeareroptions))))

Comment: Thanks Evgeny Shmanev.
This really worked for me also 1 more thing wanted to add use this below line of code to allow Authorization policy either for JWT or Azure AD Token :

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("JwtOrAzureAD", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});